# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: operator class "varchar_pattern_ops" does not accept data type integer

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, django-rest-framework, psycopg2

On running

```
heroku run python3 manage.py migrate
```

I get the below log

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: operator class "varchar_pattern_ops" does not accept data type integer
```

What is the issue with psycopg2? Please help

Comment: `psycopg2` is simply the underlying API that your Django uses to access your DB (postgres, is it?).
You have a problem in your schema.
Please attach your Document definitions, before and after the migration, to help find your problem.

Comment: i am completely new to django and i cant get what u mean by "Document definitions". Please make it clear. what should i provide?

Comment: The class definitions that you're trying to migrate, i.e. the sql tables that you defined as python classes.